# how to add vse content in the 3d view

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I currently try to manipulate the different aspect of the vse and one thing is blocking me.

I want to add a 3d scene on top of a video, so far so good, I know how to use transparent bg.
But what I want to do is for example, put a glass shader on a sphere and when i render, the video is deformed inside the sphere.

I understand thats something that must be done inside the 3d section but I did'nt found any option to add the content of the vse on the background of the 3d scene or something like this.

Even for preview to place correctly the different object could be nice instead of retry multiple times

Comment: You could render your clip from VSE into images (combining that into video later). Then in put one more plane behind the sphere so that it's visible from camera. Set your rendered video as the texture for that plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents on the VSE cannot be used on the 3D scene directly.

They would need to be rendered as image sequence or video and used as textures.

Comment: thats too bad, it coud be really helpful in many situation

Comment: Contents of the VSE and the Compositor can't be used as textures.